# Get the post id from a plugin

Tags: posts

WHile Building a plugin I need to get the post id from the function defined inside plugin.So i used

```
global $post;

$postid = $post->ID;

echo $postid;
```

and

```
$id = get_the_ID();
    echo $id;
```

but its not working.
Then I added

```
$url = explode('?', 'http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    $ID = url_to_postid($url[0]);
    echo $ID;
```

and still not working

Comment: Have you tried `get_post()`?

Comment: Please try `echo get_queried_object_id();`. If that echoes 0, your function might be running too early. In that case, try to run your function at a later action.

Comment: yes I tried.but not working!!.

Comment: Try this:
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();

Comment: Exactly when/where do you need this information?

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems I have run into while trying to accomplish something like this is: WHEN are you trying to get this information.

A lot of stuff happens in a WordPress page request. 
See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

If you just have the raw function in your plugin file, it will try to run when the plugin loads (which is very early in the process), and you will not get the info you are looking for.

I'm not sure how early you can do it, but I generally stick it at `wp`.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'get_post_id' );


function get_post_id () {
    global $wp_query;
    $post_id = $wp_query->post->ID;
}
```

The way I do this is:

```
class Main_Plugin_Class(){

public $post_id;

public __constructor(){

 ...

 add_action( 'wp', array( 'this', 'at_wp') );

}

public function at_wp(){

 $post_id = $this->get_post_id();
 $this->object_that_will_actually_do_things = new Class_For_Doing_Things($post_id);

}

private function get_post_id(){
 global $wp_query;
 $id = $wp_query->post->ID;
 return $id;
}

}
```